# How to store data in SQLite and send that to web server when connected, via JSON format

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, udp

Hi my app will do wifi scan and send the data (using JSON Array) to splunk server(web server) periodically, now at the time of wifi disconnection I cant send, so I am planning to store the scan result using SQLite database and automatically send them to server when it reconnect to the wifi network. Kindly help me how to do that.

FYI: when the user is disconnected the app will scan and store data for every 1 min and when reconnect it should send automatically the stored data to the server.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use broadcast reciever to be notified on the internet connection and in the onrecieve of the broadcast reciever perform your action follow [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/) guide for more guidance

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help , the thing is I can start the scan after disconnection but i dont know how to store them in JSON format and send them when they are reconnected to network automatically without getting request from the server.

Comment: It's pretty easy actually - JSONObject can be initialized with a string (the formatting is being made in the constructor) (see here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)
Just save what you want to send to sharedpreferences (or better sqlite and parameterized the field as TEXT) and send it once the broadcastreciever notify an OnRecieve event.